# I need to display DURATION(enddate - startdate) whose DURATION is greater than average DURATION

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the original table. the Duration is calculated by (ENDDATE - STARTDATE)

```
RESNO   RESDATE NOOFGUESTS  STARTDATE   ENDDATE 
1       01-NOV-15   5   01-FEB-16   05-FEB-16   
2       01-NOV-15   2   05-JAN-16   10-JAN-16   
3       03-NOV-15   3   05-JAN-16   15-JAN-16   
4       02-JAN-16   2   03-JAN-16   06-JAN-16   
5       15-FEB-16   3   20-FEB-16   22-FEB-16   
6       20-FEB-16   3   25-FEB-16   28-FEB-16   
7       20-FEB-16   5   22-FEB-16   25-FEB-16   
8       24-FEB-16   2   28-FEB-16   03-MAR-16   
9       28-FEB-16   10  10-MAR-16   15-MAR-16
```

I tried using the following SQL in LIVE ORACLE

```
select RESNO, (ENDDATE - STARTDATE) as Durations from reservation 
where (ENDDATE - STARTDATE) >  (sum(ENDDATE - STARTDATE) / count(*));
```

but it gives an error
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

I have also used other ways but did not got any valid result.
Please help

Comment: select RESNO, (ENDDATE - STARTDATE) as Durations from reservation 
where (ENDDATE - STARTDATE) >  (select avg(ENDDATE - STARTDATE) from reservation )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into analytical functions in SQL (AskTom has a lot on it). Here is a simple solution:

```
select * from (
  select resno,enddate - startdate duration, 
    avg(enddate - startdate) over () avg_dur
  from reservations)
where duration > avg_dur;
```